# How to configure Typegoose with GraphQL to reference subdocument to part of another document?

Tags: typegraphql, typegoose

I have a collection `User` that has two fields of the collection `Country` embedded in itas a subdocument. The `Country` collection is used as an enumerator and is used to reference before inserting it into the `User` collection. I want to apply this logic to my GraphQL and Typegoose project.

In the user.schema.ts file:

```js
import { Field, InputType, ObjectType } from 'type-graphql';
import { prop as Property, Ref } from '@typegoose/typegoose';
import { Country } from './country.model';

@ObjectType()
@InputType('UserInput')
export class User {
    @Field(type => ID)
    @Property({ required: true })
    public _id!: string;

    @Field(type => Country)
    @Property({ ref: 'Country', required: true })
    public country!: Ref<Country>;
}
```

In the country.schema.ts file:

```js
import { Field, ID, InputType, Int, ObjectType } from 'type-graphql';
import { modelOptions, prop as Property, Ref } from '@typegoose/typegoose';

@modelOptions({ schemaOptions: { collection: 'Country' } })

@ObjectType()
@InputType('CountryInput')
export class Country {
    @Field(type => ID)
    @Property({ required: true })
    _id!: string;

    @Field()
    @Property({ required: true })
    name!: string;

    @Field()
    @Property({ required: true })
    alpha2!: string;

    @Field()
    @Property({ required: true })
    alpha3!: string;

    @Field()
    @Property({ required: true })
    numeric!: string;
}
```

The user collection has a subdocument that is named "Country". The subdocument only has "id" and "name" from the "Country" collection.

```
{
    "_id" : "7392798430", 
    "country" : {
        "id"   : "69",
        "name" : "Switzerland"
    }
}
```

This is what a document in the "Country" collection looks like:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "6786876687", 
    "name" : "Switzerland", 
    "alpha2" : "CH", 
    "alpha3" : "CHE", 
    "numeric" : "789"
}
```

I want to be able to reference the country table every time I create a user. Currently, I'm attempting to query the user with the country as a property, and it gives me the error:

> Cannot return null for non-nullable field User.country.
>   Every user already has a country subdocument. None of them are null. It *is* required.

I'm not even being able to query it normally. I want to test by querying it first, and then inserting it into the user table a country not available in the country table, to test whether it would throw an error or not.

I'm using NestJS if that matters.

Comment: Has a sub-document? Or is it actually in another collection? Please show what sample document(s) actually look like stored in MongoDB.

Comment: I just added what the other collection looks like. The subdocument is referencing it.

Comment: Querying with a constraint on data in another collection requires a "join" and a **real join**. Mongoose does not do **real joins**.